# SDL2 OpenGL window appears semi-transparent (sometimes)

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

After I create a window with SDL2 and draw into it the window appears semi-transparent and doesn't always draw anything at all (fully transparent).

My code for creating the window is

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>

int main(){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    auto win = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "test",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        1920, 1080,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
    );

    auto ctx = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);

    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(win, ctx);

    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

    /* destroy window and context */

    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I haven't included error checking or context attribute setup for brevity, but no errors arise and the context is an RGBA8 context with 24-bit depth buffer at OpenGL version 3.3

Here's an image of what the window looks like:

[image: Window created]

I noticed the window border doesn't seem to be `0`, so the context may be created at a different resolution than the window itself.

I've made windows with SDL2 this exact way before and never had this issue, which leads me to believe that it is a platform bug.

If it helps, I am running KDE Plasma 5.7.1, Qt 5.7 with KDE Frameworks version 5.24.0 on 64-bit KDE neon with the open source intel drivers.

Comment: What version of SDL2?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine 2.0.4

Comment: Either redraw unconditionally or at least redraw on appropriate events. Sleep is completely unreliable.

Comment: Where's your event pump?